# Store query result in kshell variable in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I want to store the result of a query into a variable in a k-shell script. This is so far I have done:

```
WeekEndingDate=`nzsql << endl | grep KEEP | sed 's/KEEP//;s/[ ]//g' 

select 'KEEP', max(Week1) from Table_Week; 

endl` 

echo Week ending date: $WeekEndingDate

MonthEndingDate=`nzsql << endl | grep KEEP | sed 's/KEEP//;s/[ ]//g' 

select 'KEEP', max(Month1) from Table_Week; 

endl`

echo Month ending date: $MonthEndingDate
```

And the result when I run this is:

```
Week ending date: |2013060801 

Month ending date: |2013060804
```

There is a pipe which getting prefixed. I jus need the result without pipe as:

```
Week ending date: 2013060801 

Month ending date: 2013060804
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: How does the raw output from the query looks like? Since you are already using sed to remove KEEP etc, probably you can use it to remove | as well

Comment: The raw output looks like:     
   MAX
------------
 2013060801

    MAX
------------
 2013060804

Comment: The raw output doesn't contain any pipe. i dnt knw how the pipe is getting prefixed to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WeekEndingDate=`nzsql -A -t -c "select max(Week1) from Table_Week"`
echo Week ending date: ${WeekEndingDate}

MonthEndingDate=`nzsql -A -t -c "select max(Month1) from Table_Week"`
echo Month ending date: ${MonthEndingDate}
```

You are adding 'KEEP' in the sql query and then removing it from the output so it doesn't make sense to add it in the first place. Can you try the following and see if it helps:

```
WeekEndingDate=`nzsql << endl
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
select trim(max(Week1)) from Table_Week; 
endl` 

echo Week ending date: ${WeekEndingDate}

MonthEndingDate=`nzsql << endl
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
select trim(max(Month1)) from Table_Week;
endl`

echo Month ending date: ${MonthEndingDate}
```

Comment: 'KEEP' is used to trim the output. I have tried wht you suggested and now its giving this output: 
BTRIM ------------ 2013060801 (1 row) 
BTRIM ------------ 2013060804 (1 row)

Comment: you probably need to set heading off. I am not familiar with nzsql but something like what I have updated in the answer

Comment: Im sorry. But now its showing an error. Even i am a novice in not only nzsql but also unix

Comment: @Jahnavi : Try with the statements I just added

Comment: I have tried with the statements you have added Amit. Thats when i got the error

Comment: Did you try these:

WeekEndingDate=`nzsql -A -t -c "select max(Week1) from Table_Week"`
MonthEndingDate=`nzsql -A -t -c "select max(Month1) from Table_Week"`